# C++ Pointer access similar to assembly

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, assembly

Sometimes i see different array-access styles in C++ and thought it could be relative to an assembly addressing mode:

C++:

```
int * aa=new int[2];
0[aa]=15; //a little different than aa[0]
1[aa]=15;
aa[0]=15;
aa[1]=15;
printf("%d %d \n",aa[0],aa[1]);
```

Assembly:

```
__asm
{
    mov aa[0],ebx
    mov aa[1],eax
    mov 0[aa],ebx
    mov 1[aa],eax
}
```

**Is this C++ array-access notation a standard and if yes, was it derived from an assembly addressing mode?**

When i try `[aa]1=5;` , compiler gives

- "aa attribute not found",
- "missing ';' before 'constant'"
- "left operand must be l-value".

  //When i try pointer arithmetic,

  *(aa+1)=0//gives no error

  *(aa+0)=0//gives no error :)

**Is this rule same for the operator [] overloading?**

MSVC++ 2010

Thank you.

Comment: The two are unrelated - C predates 80x86 by a number of years.

Comment: Where do you see stuff like `0[aa]=15` in real C++ code? It's legal, but most people wouldn't use it unless they're smoking something which is not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a well-known quirk of C and C++, they don't really care which half of an expression goes in the square brackets `[]`. They both evaluate to the same equivalent expression:

```
*(0+aa)=15;
```

Comment: What about operator overloading [] ?

Comment: Operator overloading is completely orthogonal here, since it allows for any behaviour to be invoked when the `[]` operator is used.

Comment: @slugonamission: However, the overload must be a non-static class member, so you generally can't define an overload such that `0[aa]` is equivalent to `aa[0]`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour - of course, I was just trying to make the point that you can't contrast an overloaded `[]` operator to the C default `[]` operator

Answer (score 4):

The expression `a[b]` essentially gets translated into `*(a+b)`.
That's why this "style" `11[arr]` is possible.

The reason `[aa]11` fails is purely syntactic.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this C++ array-access notation a standard?

Yes. As long as one operand is a pointer and the other is arithmetic, `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a+b)`, so it doesn't matter whether the pointer or the index goes inside the `[]`.

> if yes, was it derived from an assembly addressing mode?

Almost certainly not. The syntax comes directly from C, which was originally developed for the PDP family of computers, where that assembly addressing mode was written `1(aa)`.

> When i try `[aa]1=5`, compiler gives (errors)

That's because the syntax for a subscript expression is specified as `postfix-expression [ expression ]`, so the operand in `[]` must come after the other.

> Is this rule same for the operator [] overloading?

No. If the operator has been overloaded then `a[b]` is equivalent to `a.operator[](b)`, and not `b.operator[](a)`.